# Invoke jQuery on Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, footable

Working on an ASP.NET/MVC5 website. I have a jQuery-based data-driven table (footable). I implemented an "infinite scroll" feature to it. On the document ready I execute footable() and it does some row styling, etc... It seems to be working well EXCEPT for one thing....

PROBLEM: Initially the table styling looks great. BUT, when I scroll, and the Ajax request retrieves more records, the rows are all displayed in the table, BUT the new rows are not styled appropriately. So, I'm thinking I have to invoke the document ready code again???? If this is the case, how can I do it?

Here's a portion of the code...

```html
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/infiniteScroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("div#loading").hide();
        });
        var moreRowsUrl = "/SearchResults/GetRecords"; //the URL to your ActionMethod        
        $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
    </script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/footable")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.footable').footable();
        });
    </script>
}

@section Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/footableStyles")
}
```

Thanks in advance for your insightful comments! :)

Comment: on the ajax `success` event, after adding the new rows, call the code to do your styling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all you're doing on document ready is:

```
$('.footable').footable();
```

So in your `success` function for the ajax request, just call the above code again.

This probably goes somewhere in your `scrollHandler` since that's what seems to be called when you scroll, but you didn't post the code